# How to loop 3 dimension array using foreach PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Below is foreach and the 3 dimension arrays, no problem with the looping but i cannot sepcify which array to echo, they must me the whole arrays like echo $subvalue, any better solutions with looping 3 dimension array?  i actually feel weird with this looping. Thanks in adv

```
foreach ($stories as $key => $story){
    //echo "<br />";
        foreach($story as $subkey => $subvalue){
            echo $subvalue."<br />";
                foreach($subvalue as $key => $subsubvalue){
                    echo $subsubvalue."<br />";
                }
        }
}

Array
(
    [270] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 36
            [user_email] => aaa@hotmail.com
            [sid] => 270
            [story_name] => Story C
            [photo_url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => story_photos/2012/0322/361332381418153311.jpg
                    [1] => story_photos/2012/0322/361332393792911587.jpg
                )

            [photo_added_date] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1332381418
                    [1] => 1332393792
                )

        )

    [269] => Array
        (
        [uid] => 36
        [user_email] => aaa@hotmail.com
        [sid] => 269
        [story_name] => Story B
        [photo_url] => Array
            (
                [0] => story_photos/2012/0322/361332381406580761.jpg
            )

        [photo_added_date] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1332381406
            )

    )

[268] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 36
        [user_email] => aaa@hotmail.com
        [sid] => 268
        [story_name] => Story A
        [photo_url] => Array
            (
                [0] => story_photos/2012/0322/361332381393552719.jpg
            )

        [photo_added_date] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1332381393
            )

    )
```

)

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 4):

Why not try this :

```
foreach ($stories as $key => $story){
    if(is_array($story)){
        foreach($story as $subkey => $subvalue){
            if(is_array($subvalue)){
                foreach($subvalue as $key => $subsubvalue){
                    echo $subsubvalue."<br />";
                }
            } else {
                echo $subvalue."<br />";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo $story."<br />";
    }
}
```

Also, I am not sure because your question isn't really clear or specified.

Answer (score 3):

Or

```
function echoArray( $array )
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $cell)
    {
        if ( true == is_array($cell) )
        {
           echoArray($cell);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "$cell<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

It works for N dimensionnal array

An improved version to know the depth and use different css class for depth and to use set the tag in which the value should be added:

Eg: for depth 0 the class will by arrayclass_0, for depth 1 arrayclass_1, etc...

```
/**
$array : The array
$depth: The depth ( you should always set it to 0)
$cssclassprefix: The css class prefix you want to set
$tag: the default tag to use to render
$arraytagkey: An optionnal key in your array to extract the tag to use
*/
function echoArray( $array, $depth=0, $cssclassprefix='arrayclass_', $tag='div', $arraytagkey = '' )
{
    if ( 0 != strcmp($arraytagkey) && isset($array[$arraytagkey]) )
    {
       $tag=$array[$arraytagkey];
    }
    foreach ($array as $key => $cell)
    {
        if ( true == is_array($cell) )
        {
           echoArray($cell, $depth+1, $cssclassprefix, $tag, $arraytagkey);
        }
        else
        {
            $matches = array();
            if ( 0 != preg_match("/^(img|iframe|input)$/i",$tag) )
            {
                if ( 0 != strcasecmp('input',$tag) )
                {
                   echo "<input class='$cssclassprefix$depth' value='$cell' />";
                }
                else
                {
                   echo "<$tag class='$cssclassprefix$depth' src='$cell' />";
                }
            }
            else if( 0 != preg_match("/^(br|hr)$/i",$tag) )
            {
                echo "$cell<$tag />";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<$tag class='$cssclassprefix$depth'>$cell</$tag>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is this for unlimited depth loops?  I actually just need second level loops.

Comment: It is for unlimited multiarray depth (in fact there is a depth limit for recursion in php5 but i don't remember it, because the limit is used to avoid infinite recursion, so segfault)

Comment: @grifos it works, but how do i call each $value?   
for example $value['user_email'].

Comment: I don't really get what you want, because the function is generic and will display each array cell (so each value) and recursively loop when  a cell is an array. I edited my post to add the array key names in the loop, it might help, you.

Comment: Yes, it will display each array cell but i mean when output to HTML. I would like something like <div><?php $value['user_email'] ?></div>, so i can call each value in html.

Hope you get what i mean. thx again

Comment: In your case MrCode answer seems to fit what you want. I thought you wanted a clean way to go throught multidimensionnal array, but you know exactly how you array is constructed so use MrCode version. Mine is too generic for your needs.Other wise if you want to put info in <div></div> tag you just have to change the echo.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question, but note, your third loop is this:

```
foreach ($subvalue as $key => $subsubvalue){
```

But you've already used $key in the first loop:

```
foreach ($stories as $key => $story){
```

You should change the third to:

```
foreach ($subvalue as $subsubkey => $subsubvalue){
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just wanting to loop through and get access to the photo_urls and other data? If that's the case then here's a simple example of how you can access the data:

```
foreach($stories as $key => $story)
{

    // here you can echo the $store['user_email']  etc
    echo 'Email: ' . $story['user_email'] . '<br />';

    // loop over the photo urls
    foreach($story['photo_url'] as $photo_url)
    {
        echo 'Photo URL: ' . $photo_url . '<br />';
    }

    // loop over the photo added dates
    foreach($story['photo_added_date'] as $photo_added_date)
    {
        echo 'Photo Date: ' . $photo_added_date . '<br />';
    }

}
```

If you're wanting to recursively search the array then the other answers are what you want.

Comment: Yes, i just want to have second level loops